# Can I use an Acces query to create a temp table from APPEND

Tags: ms-access, append

I'm trying to write a query that I can call from with Excel that will return the results from a handlfull of tables in a single list.

I could create the table I need from APPEND and just pull that into excel, but the tables I want in the APPEND will change from time to time and I'd rather just add them into the append than keep creating the tables I need and deleting the ones i don't need.

I have a monthly invoices from a number of clients in tables for each client and month. The total number of invoices per month is ~1m. I started just joining them into one large table but it starts to add up to a massive database quite quickly. Most of the time I'd only need to query the first couple of months but everyone in a while I'd have to go back longer.

What I want to do is have a query for each company that I can alter to pull back varying groups of months, but without actually creating the table.

i.e  append 
Company A Jan,
Company A Feb,
etc

Is there away to do this in a query without creating an actual table

Answer (score 0):

I needed a UNION query.

I knew it was an issue with terminology.